# Adding a comment to Facebook post acts weird when using Safari

Tags: safari, facebook

I'm having this weird issue when commenting on a *Facebook* post on *Safari*.

It mostly happens when I try to add a <kbd>space</kbd> after adding *punctuation* like comma <kbd>,</kbd>.

What happens is that the cursor is thrown back to the starting point of comment and erases almost all the text I have entered before the *punctuation*.

This only happens when trying from *Safari* while it works normally on browsers like *Chrome*, *Firefox* etc.

Did any of you run into the same issue? Is there any workaround to overcome that?

*Safari* - *Version 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2)*
*OS X*   - *(El Capitan) Version 10.11.1 (15B42)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this issue was resolved when I disabled the `Grammarly` extension which I used with `Safari` Thanks [Agentroadkill](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/81404/agentroadkill) for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem as well a few weeks ago, I believe I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and it fixed itself never to glitch out again. I should note though that it was a different website, I'm running Yosemite, and my memory is always not the greatest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I'm afraid my issue wasn't fixed when I try using the  `tab`

Comment: Huh. I definitely had this issue, I just wish I remember what made it go away. I'll keep this in min and see if it comes to me

Comment: Sure. Btw I just figured out that when I disable the Grammarly plugin it seems working fine. I'll confirm if I didn't get that issue for the next day :)